# php - mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

platform: windows server 2008 R1

I'm trying to configure ikbin usenet indexer on my local server.

I installed mysql, a php interpreter, and all is well until I try to open the admin.php page. The page itself loads fine, but I see a mysql error at the top.

When trying to connect to mysql to allow me to add newsgroups to index, or just going to the default php page, I receive an error connecting to the mysql database:

> Database error: pconnect(localhost, MySQLuser, $Password) failed.
>   MySQL Error: ()

The ikbin package comes with some admin pages where you set passwords for db access, but it keeps failing, and I am certain i'm entering the correct passwords...

I don't know much about either php or mysql. Is there any fundamental newbie thing I might be doing wrong? THANKS

Comment: Are you sure msql is running properly and the database exists?

Comment: thanks for the answer but no, I'm not sure of either and not sure how to check. I have a long time in software development, so maybe if you give me some guidance I won't be too stupid :-) ... I do have MySQL workbench installed, and I think I created the database itself using a script that came with ikbin... but I'm not sure what a 'database' is in MySQL. Is it like Oracle where there's only one db but many tablespaces, or like SQL Server where there's one server and many databases?

Comment: ok, now I can answer your questions: Yes. both are verified.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the following code.,it may helps for your problem...
$dbConnection = mysql_pconnect( $myHostname, $myUsername, $myPassword  );

if ( !mysql_ping( $dbConnection ) )
{
   $dbConnection = mysql_pconnect( $myHostname, $myUsername, $myPassword  );
}